# Remap foreign key constraint after table rename with EF Core code first migration

Tags: entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, blazor, code-first

I have to rename a table A that is targetted by a foreign key constraint of another table C. I then have to add a new table B and remap the old foreign key constraint link "A <-> B" to C, so that now B and C are linked.

How can I do that with Blazor, EF core code first? It would be ok the remove the foreign key constraint "A <-> C" and create a new "B <-> C" one. I just don't know how to write that down as C# migration code.

Background: The automatically created migration didn't work due to exactly that foreign key restriction. Instead of simply renaming everything, code for dropping the table and recreating it was created, causing a foreign key constraint error during execution of the migration. So I rewrote it to simply rename the table and create the new one, but that remapped the foreign key to the renamed table, which is not what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself: I can use migrationBuider.DropForeignKey() and migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey().